# SOQL query of MetadataComponentDependency: "Dependency API is not enabled"

Tags: soql, metadata, tooling-api, release, package-dependency

I'm trying out the Dependency API (Winter '20 beta release) to help me draw package boundaries.

I ran a test query from the Dev Console using the Tooling API but immediately hit  the error

> [object Object]: Dependency API is not enabled.

Perhaps I misunderstand the availability of beta features, but I didn't think I'd have to opt in to anything.  My org is on the Winter '20 release.

Comment: Also, FWIW, this same Tooling API query is working in a Winter '20 sandbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is following this: Dependency API is now (Spring '20) available in all environments including production orgs.

Answer (score 4):

As per [Vlad's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/296564/102), the Dependency API is now GA in Spring '20 (v48.0).

---

Clarification provided by [Vladimir Gerasimov](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004d646U) about the current Winter '20 Beta functionality:

> Apologies for the confusion. Since Dependency API is currently in beta, **it's only available in sandboxes**.
>
> I think they way it's documented in our release notes is a bit confusing as it says:
>   *Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience, Salesforce Classic, and all versions of the Salesforce app in Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions, sandboxes only.*
>
> It's currently not supported in production DE orgs. Good news are that we are planning to expand this beta into production in the next release.

---

I tested it in a Sandbox (cs93) with the developer console. It seemed to be enabled.

[image]

The same SOQL query `Select Id from MetadataComponentDependency` in a production org produced a GACK for me... so that is something I'll follow up on.

> [object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1691316497-63528 (-541748943)

On NA87 I got the same error message you did:

> **DEPENDENCY_API_UNSUPPORTED_EXCEPTION**
>   [object Object]: Dependency API is not enabled

[image]

The [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_api_metadatacomponentdependency_beta.htm) say:

> **Where:** This change applies to Lightning Experience, Salesforce Classic, and all versions of the Salesforce app in Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions, sandboxes only.

So I'd expect it to work in a production org. I'll [message the PM](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00004d646U) to see what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for testing and passing this on, Daniel!  May I ask how you found the right community Chatter Group and PM for this question?  I'd like to collaborate with PMs/product teams (with similarly vetted and well-formulated questions) in the future.

Comment: I was on the pilot for the dependency API last year and presented on it at Dreamforce. So I'd been in and out of the group for a bit. I know Vlad as well. He's a great PM for helping out the community, so assuming he isn't crazy busy we should get some help. That said, we are in the lead up to Dreamforce, so lots will be going on withing Salesforce.

Comment: I see. I'll follow that thread you started.  It's working for me in a Winder '20 sandbox, so there seems to be a definite work-around...

Comment: Ha, @Daniel Ballinger, I think it was right in front of our noses and we missed it.  At the end of your final quote, from the release notes, it says "**sandboxes only**" (presumably with the exception of dev orgs).  Granted it doesn't explain the GACK

Comment: Vladimir responded, "Since Dependency API is currently in beta, it's only available in sandboxes... It's currently not supported in production DE orgs. Good news are that we are planning to expand this beta into production in the next release."  If you want to update your answer with this I'll mark it accepted.  Thanks again, Daniel!

Comment: Updated. I think the GACK on my other org was related to in being in the pilot. It's likely messed something up.